# PHP Select form using php to pull all entries from database and display selected one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi everyone what i plan on doing is to list all my users from my table, display them in a list and then have the current entry in the table highlighted in the drop down list.

This is my current code:

```
print "<option value=".$row2['user_id']." if($row2['user_id']==$row['user_id']){ echo 'selected=\"selected\"';}>".$row2['fname']." ".$row2['lname']."</option>";
```

but it does not work.

At the moment my current code which does work is like this:

```
<?
//$results4 = mysql_query("select * from user_info order by fname");

$data2 = "select * from user_info order by fname";

$result2 = mysql_query($data2);
print "<select name=\"timesheet_approver_1\">";
print "<option value=".$row['user_id']." selected='selected'>".$row['fname']." ".$row['lname']."</option>";
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
print "<option value=".$row2['user_id'].">".$row2['fname']." ".$row2['lname']."</option>";
}
print "</select>";
?>
```

This lists all my entries but adds the one in the table listed at the top. Im just stuck as to how i can just list all entries and have the one in the table highlighted.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot embed `if` statements within `print` statements as you have attempted.

But, you can compare without the `if` using the [`ternary operator`](https://www.php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

`print "<option value='".$row2['user_id']."' " . ($row2['user_id']==$row['user_id'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ) . '>' . $row2['fname']." ".$row2['lname']. "</option>";`

Works like so:

`echo ( $a == $b ? 'a==b evaluates true' : 'a==b evaluates false' );`

From the manual

`"The expression (expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3) evaluates to expr2 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 if expr1 evaluates to FALSE."`

Comment: Awesome thank you so much ! i actually see how it should be and this works great for me thanks for all the help guys ! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are putting the first iten always selected.

```
//| this line here is outside your loop which means that even 
//| if there a true to your expression it will left two options with selected attribute and
//| the first one will be selected.
print "<option value=".$row['user_id']." selected='selected'>".$row['fname']."      ".$row['lname']."</option>";


while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    print "<option value=".$row2['user_id'].">".$row2['fname']." ".$row2['lname']."</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the input and helping me figure this out i really appreciate it.

Just for anyone reading this entry this has now been resolved but hopefully the code i used should help someone one, i have posted my working code below.

This simplifies my code and does the job perfectly, hope this can help anyone else with a similar issue, thanks :)

```
<?

//$results4 = mysql_query("select * from user_info order by fname");
$data2a = "select * from user_info order by fname";

$result2a = mysql_query($data2a);

print "<select name=\"timesheet_approver_2\">";

//print "<option value=".$row['timesheet_approver_2']." selected='selected'>".$row['timesheet_approver_2']." ".$row['timesheet_approver_2']."</option>";

while ($row2a = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2a)) {

//print "<option value=".$row2a['user_id'].">".$row2a['fname']." ".$row2a['lname']." (".$row2a['user_id'].")</option>";

print "<option value='".$row2a['user_id']."' " . ($row2a['user_id']==$row['timesheet_approver_2'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ) . '>' . $row2a['fname']." ".$row2a['lname']. "</option>";
}
print "</select>";


?>
```

Comment: i apologise for the code looking messy, if you know a way for me to make it look neater please message me and i'll tidy this up.